# FFMPEG Crop video and insert gif same time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, infinite-loop

```
                $command = 'ffmpeg -ss 6 -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i logo.gif -filter_complex \ "crop=in_w-2*28:in_h-2*25;[0:v][1:v]overlay=15:H-h-25:shortest=1" -codec:v libx264 out.mp4';
```

i can't manage both gif and video process. Can someone help ? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input and output pads should be clearly labelled and used.

```
ffmpeg -ss 6 -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i logo.gif -filter_complex \ 
"[0:v]crop=in_w-2*28:in_h-2*25[base];[base][1:v]overlay=15:H-h-25:shortest=1" \
-codec:v libx264 out.mp4
```